# Add another framework with Cocoapods

Tags: ios, xcode, opencv, cocoapods

I am using AFNetworking and 2 more frameworks using cocoapods in my project, and now I want to add opencv2.framework in the same project

Is there any different technique of doing this?
Because when I add opencv2.framework in my project (already using cocoapods) it is showing errors:

> > Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
> >       "_CMTimeMake", referenced from:
> >           -[CvVideoCamera createVideoDataOutput] in opencv2(cap_ios_video_camera.o)
> >       "_AVCaptureSessionPresetLow", referenced from:
> >           -[CvAbstractCamera createCaptureSession] in opencv2(cap_ios_abstract_camera.o)
> >           -[CvAbstractCamera updateSize] in opencv2(cap_ios_abstract_camera.o)
> >       "_AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh", referenced from:
> >           -[CvAbstractCamera updateSize] in opencv2(cap_ios_abstract_camera.o)
> >       "_AVCaptureSessionPreset352x288", referenced from:
> >           -[CvAbstractCamera init] in opencv2(cap_ios_abstract_camera.o)
> >           -[CvAbstractCamera updateSize] in opencv2(cap_ios_abstract_camera.o)
> >       "_AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill", referenced from:
> >           -[CvAbstractCamera createVideoPreviewLayer] in opencv2(cap_ios_abstract_camera.o)
> >       "_AVVideoCodecKey", referenced from:
> >           -[CvPhotoCamera createStillImageOutput] in opencv2(cap_ios_photo_camera.o)
> >           -[CvVideoCamera createVideoFileOutput] in opencv2(cap_ios_video_camera.o)
> >       "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVAssetReaderTrackOutput", referenced from:
> >           objc-class-ref in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
> >       "_AVMediaTypeVideo", referenced from:
> >           -[CvAbstractCamera createCaptureDevice] in opencv2(cap_ios_abstract_camera.o)
> >           -[CvAbstractCamera setDesiredCameraPosition:] in opencv2(cap_ios_abstract_camera.o)
> >           -[CvAbstractCamera lockFocus] in opencv2(cap_ios_abstract_camera.o)
> >           -[CvAbstractCamera unlockFocus] in opencv2(cap_ios_abstract_camera.o)
> >           -[CvAbstractCamera lockExposure] in opencv2(cap_ios_abstract_camera.o)
> >           -[CvAbstractCamera unlockExposure] in opencv2(cap_ios_abstract_camera.o)
> >           -[CvAbstractCamera lockBalance] in opencv2(cap_ios_abstract_camera.o)
> >           ...
> >       "_AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium", referenced from:
> >           -[CvAbstractCamera updateSize] in opencv2(cap_ios_abstract_camera.o)
> >       "_AVVideoHeightKey", referenced from:
> >           -[CvVideoCamera createVideoFileOutput] in opencv2(cap_ios_video_camera.o)
> >       "_AVVideoCodecH264", referenced from:
> >           -[CvVideoCamera createVideoFileOutput] in opencv2(cap_ios_video_camera.o)
> >       "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor", referenced from:
> >           objc-class-ref in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
> >           objc-class-ref in opencv2(cap_ios_video_camera.o)
> >       "_AVVideoCodecJPEG", referenced from:
> >           -[CvPhotoCamera createStillImageOutput] in opencv2(cap_ios_photo_camera.o)
> >       "_AVVideoWidthKey", referenced from:
> >           -[CvVideoCamera createVideoFileOutput] in opencv2(cap_ios_video_camera.o)
> >       "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFNetworkReachabilityManager", referenced from:
> >           type metadata accessor for __ObjC.AFNetworkReachabilityManager in Config.o
> >       "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVAssetWriter", referenced from:
> >           objc-class-ref in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
> >           objc-class-ref in opencv2(cap_ios_video_camera.o)
> >       "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVCaptureStillImageOutput", referenced from:
> >           objc-class-ref in opencv2(cap_ios_photo_camera.o)
> >       "_AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480", referenced from:
> >           -[CvAbstractCamera initWithParentView:] in opencv2(cap_ios_abstract_camera.o)
> >           -[CvAbstractCamera updateSize] in opencv2(cap_ios_abstract_camera.o)
> >       "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVAssetReader", referenced from:
> >           objc-class-ref in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
> >       "_AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720", referenced from:
> >           -[CvAbstractCamera updateSize] in opencv2(cap_ios_abstract_camera.o)
> >       "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer", referenced from:
> >           objc-class-ref in opencv2(cap_ios_abstract_camera.o)
> >       "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVURLAsset", referenced from:
> >           objc-class-ref in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
> >       "_CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer", referenced from:
> >           -[CaptureDelegate captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
> >           -[CvVideoCamera captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] in opencv2(cap_ios_video_camera.o)
> >       "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVCaptureVideoDataOutput", referenced from:
> >           objc-class-ref in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
> >           objc-class-ref in opencv2(cap_ios_video_camera.o)
> >       "_AVFileTypeMPEG4", referenced from:
> >           -[CvVideoCamera createVideoFileOutput] in opencv2(cap_ios_video_camera.o)
> >       "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVCaptureDeviceInput", referenced from:
> >           objc-class-ref in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
> >           objc-class-ref in opencv2(cap_ios_abstract_camera.o)
> >       "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVCaptureDevice", referenced from:
> >           objc-class-ref in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
> >           objc-class-ref in opencv2(cap_ios_abstract_camera.o)
> >       "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFHTTPRequestOperationManager", referenced from:
> >           l__CATEGORY_AFHTTPRequestOperationManager_$_ in Constants.o
> >           type metadata accessor for __ObjC.AFHTTPRequestOperationManager in Constants.o
> >       "_CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp", referenced from:
> >           -[CvVideoCamera captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:] in opencv2(cap_ios_video_camera.o)
> >       "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CLImageEditor", referenced from:
> >           type metadata accessor for __ObjC.CLImageEditor in MultiImagePickerViewController.o
> >       "_AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto", referenced from:
> >           -[CvAbstractCamera updateSize] in opencv2(cap_ios_abstract_camera.o)
> >       "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVCaptureSession", referenced from:
> >           objc-class-ref in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
> >           objc-class-ref in opencv2(cap_ios_abstract_camera.o)
> >       "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFHTTPResponseSerializer", referenced from:
> >           type metadata accessor for __ObjC.AFHTTPResponseSerializer in Config.o
> >       "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVAssetWriterInput", referenced from:
> >           objc-class-ref in opencv2(cap_avfoundation.o)
> >           objc-class-ref in opencv2(cap_ios_video_camera.o)
> >       "_AFStringFromNetworkReachabilityStatus", referenced from:
> >           static .Config.(reachability (.Config.Type) -> ((status : Swift.String, connected : Swift.Bool) -> ()) -> ()).(closure #1) in Config.o
> >     ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
> >     clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

But when I am using opencv2.framework in new project without cocoapods it is working fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Link your project against `CoreMedia` framework. And it seems like `AVFoundation` has to be added too